# How can I link symbols over a mathematical expression in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, typography

I would like to typeset this image with a LaTeX expression :
[image: a sequence of characters (a greek tau I guess, \vee sign, \lnot, \in sign, \square), and it has links between the tau and the squares]

In this expression, we have a sequence of characters (a greek tau I guess, `\vee` sign, `\lnot`, `\in` sign, `\square`), and, most importantly, it has links between the tau and the squares.

How can I make this in LaTeX as a mathematical equation or as a graph ? ; do I need a library like TikZ ? Of course, I would also like to be able to add and/or move symbols later.

In a less important way, can we control the space before and after a symbol like \in ?

NB : This is called an assembly and it comes from the book Theory of Sets by Nicolas Bourbaki.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome! Check the `tikzmarks` package. https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple with `pstricks`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb, upgreek}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \Rnode{T}{\mathbf{\uptau}} \vee \lnot \in \Rnode{S1}{\square} \mathbf{A'}\in \Rnode{S2}{\square} \mathbf{A''}
    \psset{linejoin=1, angle=90, nodesep=2pt}
    \ncbar{T}{S1}\ncbar[armA=15pt]{T}{S2}\]%

    \end{document}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!